# blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload direct upload to S3

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload, amazon-s3, blueimp

I'm trying to implement blueimp jquery uploader. I want it to upload directly to S3 (without PHP script in the middle). I found an example [here](http://www.designedbyaturtle.co.uk/2013/direct-upload-to-s3-with-a-little-help-from-jquery/) and followed the steps and it worked (partially). But I could not find anything good for muti-file upload.

What I want to do is to have multiple file uploader with a UI feedback just like in this [example](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/index.html).

Does anybody have an example to follow for this scenario?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get blueimp to perfectly upload to s3, it would still take advantage of my servers tmp folder.

I ended up switching over to [plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) which does upload directly to s3, and has a built in UI ( I just created my own to match the rest of my site).

- [Uploading Directly to S3](http://www.plupload.com/docs/Upload-to-Amazon-S3)
- [Full Example](https://github.com/moxiecode/plupload/blob/master/examples/jquery/s3.php)

I'm not using the multiple file feature but you could do something like

foreach file you are uploading:

```
var multipart_params = {
            'key': config['key'],
            'Filename': config['key'],
            'acl': 'public-read',
            'Content-Type': '',
            'AWSAccessKeyId': config['awskey'],
            'policy': config['policy'],
            'signature': config['signature']
        };


up.settings.multipart_params = multipart_params;
up.start();
```

Hope that helps :)